# Ошибка после отправки картинки Телеграм-боту

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, pillow

В предыдущем коде:

```
import telebot
from PIL import Image
from random import randint
import requests
import json
token = "<token>"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=token)
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start_handler(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Фарту мастер ауе")
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
def picture(message):
    im = message.photo[-1].convert('RGBA')
    result = requests.post("https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/emotion/v1.0/recognize", data=content, headers={"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
                                "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "<key>"})
    face_result = json.loads(result.text)
    im2 = message.photo[-1].convert('RGBA')
    mask = Image.open(random.choose(["mask.png", "mask1.png", "mask2.png"])).convert('RGBA')
    for i in range(len(face_result)):
        rectangle = face_result[i]['faceRectangle']
        x = rectangle['left']
        y = rectangle['top']
        w = rectangle['width']
        h = rectangle['height']
        box = (x, y, x + w, y + h)
        m = im2.resize((w, h))
        im.paste(m, box, m)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, im2)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def polegche(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Полегче, я не делаю мемы из текста.")
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Новая ошибка, когда я отправляю боту картинку он выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:\Itog_Proect\bot.py", line 32, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 222, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 246, in
__threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 103, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 54, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)   File "E:\Itog_Proect\bot.py", line 13, in picture
    im = message.photo[-1].convert('RGBA') AttributeError: 'PhotoSize' object has no attribute 'convert'
```

Comment: Забыл сказать : бот должен заменять лица на рандомные маски и выдовать изображение

Comment: `message.photo[-1]` вернул объект `PhotoSize`, а у того нет метода `convert`, почему и как я хз :)

Comment: @gil9red, просто потому что это такой "именованный кортеж" от библиотеки pyTelegramBotApi https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/types.py#L386

Comment: @Spark74, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь со статьёй [mcve]. Вам нужно самому разобраться в коде, который у вас есть. А публиковать тут эту портянку (особенно вместе с ключами доступа) — плохая идея.

Comment: @gil9red Это я знаю, но как достать объект не фотосайз, а именно само изображение

Comment: Всё решено................................

Comment: Хорошо. Как именно?